# How to make a page scrolled down when a link is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a page that has a link. When the user pressed the link he goes to a page which has a lot of text. I want the scrolled always be at the bottom of the screen. How can I do that ?

Please let me know if something is not clear.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have control over second page?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the link refer to a [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) in the document, rather than the whole document. The browser will automatically scroll there.

You'd have something like this:

**document-1.html**:

```
<div id="some-content">Foo</div>
<div id="other-content">Bar</div>
```

**index.html**:

```
<a href="document-1.html#some-content">Link to some content</a>
<a href="document-1.html#other-content">Link to other content</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it out but it didn't work. I already pass value and I am using php page like so `<a href="view_Customers.php?CustomerID= <?php echo $CusID ?>"</a>` How can I make it work ? Thanks again!

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work? The example you gave wasn't using fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor links, for this, you should have a link like  `href="/nextpage.html#anchor"`

And add `<div id="anchor"></div>` to you destination page, in a part which should scrolled up

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it out but it didn't work. I already pass value and I am using php page like so `<a href="view_Customers.php?CustomerID= <?php echo $CusID ?>"</a>` How can I make it work ? Thanks again!